# Welche vollständigen Teekesselchen gibt es?

Tags: noun, curiosity, homonym

Zwei oder mehr Wörter, die [Homonyme](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Verzeichnis:Deutsch/Homonyme) sind, werden bei unterschiedlicher Bedeutung gleich ausgesprochen (*homophon*) oder gleich geschrieben (*homograph*) oder beides. Die Wörter haben dabei unterschiedliche Etymologien, sonst wären sie dasselbe Wort mit mehreren Bedeutungen (*polysem*).

[image: Äquivokation { Polysemie | Homonymie {Homographie | Homophonie} }]

Ich möchte mich hier auf Substantive beschränken. Bei diesen dürfen sich [„Teekesselchen“](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1048/can-teekesselchen-mean-homonym) nach üblichem Verständnis im Genus und der Flexionsklasse (v.a. GenSg, DatPl) unterscheiden. Eine Übereinstimmung wird entweder nur in irgendeiner Wortform (bei gleichem Kasus und Numerus) oder im NomSg verlangt, z.B. *die Bank* und *der/die Bulle*.

> - NomSg *die Bank*, GenSg *der Bank*, NomPl *die Bänke* ↯ *die Banken*, DatPl *den Bänken* ↯ *den Banken*: ‘bench’ ↯ ‘bank’
> - NomSg *der Bulle* ↯ *die Bulle*, GenSg *des Bullen* ↯ *der Bulle*, NomPl *die Bullen*, DatPl *den Bullen*: ‘bull’ ↯ ‘bulla’

Ich suche allerdings nach vollständigen Homonymen im Deutschen, also solchen Substantiven, die in Geschlecht und allen Flexionsformen gleich sind, aber unterschiedliche Herkunft aufweisen. Es gibt welche, z.B. *der Ball*, aber welche noch?

> - NomSg *der Ball*, GenSg *des Ball(e)s*, NomPl *die Bälle*, DatPl *den Bällen*: ‘ball’ (‘bowl’ ↯ ‘prom’)

PS: Eine gemeinsame indoeuropäische Wurzel soll nicht als gleiche Herkunft gelten. Eine Entlehnung aus unterschiedlichen Sprachen genügt mir als unterschiedliche Etymologie.

Comment: Falls das nicht klar rüberkam: _Ball_ wäre mein Vorschlag für ein echtes Homonym, da die Kugel germanische und der Tanz griechische Wurzeln hat.

Comment: Also, gesucht sind Wörter, die in Genus und Flexion übereinstimmen, aber dennoch unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben und auch nicht miteinander verwandt sind.   Ich denke, du solltest den gewünschten (Nicht-)Verwandtschaftsgrad noch etwas näher beschreiben. Bspw. wäre *Bank* womöglich auch noch zu nah verwandt (ganz abgesehen von der Flexion), zumal die Ursprungsbedeutung dieselbe ist.

Comment: Ich bin mir auch nicht ganz sicher, welche Worte du akzeptierst. Wie wäre es mit "Hahn"? Der Hahn kann sowohl ein Vogel als auch ein Wasserhahn sein. Und "Nagel"? Ein Nagel befindet sich am Ende eines Fingers, aber einen Nagel kann man auch benutzen, um ein Bild an die Wand zu hängen. Würden diese 2 Beispiele dir passen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Besser so? _Hahn_ dürfte akzeptabel sein, wobei ich mir nicht sicher bin, ob der Rohrabschluss und der Waffenabzug eine andere Herkunft haben (z.B. verwandt mit _Haken_) als die männlichen Vögel. Beim Nagel würde ich hingegen intuitiv einen gemeinsamen Ursprung (also Polysemie) vermuten.

Comment: @Crissov: Japp.

Comment: Ausgesprochen naheliegend "Das Teekesselchen"

Answer (score 4):

## [die Mandel](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Mandel)

Hat als botanischer und medizinischer Begriff griechische Wurzeln, bezeichnet aber auch ein altes Mengenmaß und eine Garbe auf dem Feld und hat in dieser Bedeutung lateinische Wurzeln, die laut Wiktionary vermutlich auf manus=Hand zurückgehen.

## [die Miete](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Miete)

einerseits ein Entgelt und als solches ein Wort mit germanischer Wurzel, die "Lohn, Bezahlung" bedeutet, andererseits ein landwirtschaftlicher Begriff für einen Stapel oder Haufen, der auf ein lateinisches Wort für "kegel- oder pyramidenförmige Figur" zurückgeführt wird

## [die Limo](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Limo)

Kurzwort sowohl für Limonade als auch Limousine. In ersterer Bedeutung mit mehreren Varianten der Aussprache und Deklination, von denen aber zumindest jeweils eine mit denen der zweiten Bedeutung übereinstimmen. (Wenn man Wiktionary da folgen will - ich würde das 'i' abhängig von der Bedeutung unterschiedlich aussprechen.)

Comment: Wenn Du die zweite Bedeutung bei Wiktionary akzeptierst, auch noch: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Luser

Comment: leider finde ich keine herkunft der schraubenmutter, aber je nachdem, kann das auch ein kandidat sein.

Comment: @Armin Nein, _Mutter_ fällt wegen der unterschiedlichen Pluralformen (_Mütter_ vs. _Muttern_) aus.

Comment: stimmt, dadran habe ich gar nicht gedacht. ich habe nur auf die fälle im singular geachtet -.-

Answer (score 2):

### das Wachsen

In seiner Verwendung als substantivertes Verb kann *das Wachsen* folgende verschiedene Bedeutungen haben:

> 1. **an Größe oder Menge zunehmen, sich vermehren, zunehmen**
>      Das Verb *wachsen* stammt vom althochdeutschen [*wahsan*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=wachsen) mit der indo-europäischen Wurzel  `*(a)u̯eg- *aug-` (vermehren).
> 2. **mit Wachs einreiben**
>      Schon im Althochdeutschen finden wir [*wahsen*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Wachs) als Verb für *mit Wachs beschmieren, glätten*. Dies geht auf die indo-europäische Wurzel `*u̯okso-` für Wachs zurück.

Die noch im Althochdeutschen möglich erscheinende verschiedene Aussprache zumindest des Verbs hat sich im modernen Deutsch verloren. Neben *das Wachsen* kennen wir natürlich auch noch *den Wuchs* als eigenständiges, nicht homonymes Substantiv.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe nicht gefunden, ob du Eigennamen akzeptierst:

*Atlas* (Kartenwerk, zurückgehend auf den Titanen Atlas aus der griechischen Mythologie) und Atlas (Das Gebirge in Marokko - Wortherkunft aus dem Arabischen). Das Gebirge hat natürlich keinen Plural...

Der restliche Katalog mag ein paar haben, die du akzeptieren wirst, und sicher auch ein paar, die du ablehnen willst, weil z.B. Genus anders ist oder irgendeine Flexion unterschiedlich sein mag:

*Bremse* (Insekt und Fahrzeugbremse) - Kann mir dazu beim besten Willen keine gemeinsame Herkunft oder Zusammenhang ausmalen. Beide Bedeutungen kommen aus dem Germanischen Sprachraum - Anscheinend kommt das Insekt vom "summen", die Fahrzeugbremse vom "drängen, zwängen".

Zeitungs*ente* und die im Teich. Die Zeitungsente ist ein Reimport aus dem Französischen, die beiden Begriffe haben im Deutschen eigentlich überhaupt keinen Zusammenhang. Er ergibt sich erst aus der Rückübersetzung aus dem Französischen.

Die *Fuge* als Mauerfuge (von deutsch "fügen") und das Musikstück (von lat. "fuga", die Flucht)

*Golf* als Sportart - aus dem Schottischen - und Der Golf von z.B. Mexiko (aus dem Italienischen). Teilen aber nicht das gleiche Genus.

*Otter* als Mardertier, dessen Name vom mittelhochdeutschen "Wasser" zu stammen scheint, und die Schlange, die angeblich durch einen sprachlichen "Unfall", bei der der "Natter" das "N" verloren ging, entstanden ist. Teilen auch nicht dasselbe Genus.

*Rock* als Kleidungsstück und Musikrichtung.

Das *Tor* als Eingangstor möglicherweise aus dem Griechischen, oder *der Tor* als Narr, anscheinend aus dem slawischen Sprachraum. Leiderleider auch nicht dasselbe Geschlecht.

*Der Funk* als Musikrichtung und als elektromagnetische Welle (erstaunlicherweise schon wieder Musik) - Gleiche Aussprache war ja nicht gefragt.

Comment: Da nach Wörtern mit gleichem Genus gefragt ist (übrigens **das** Genus), passen _Golf_, _Otter_ und _Tor_ nicht. – Zur Herkunft der _Ente_ (‘Falschmeldung’) gibt es verschiedene Theorien. Falls es eine Lehnübersetzung von frz. _canard_ ist, wäre es dasselbe Wort; falls es die Abkürzung _n. t._ sein sollte, dagegen unabhängig.

Comment: Das Atlas-Gebirge und das Kartenwerk scheinen beide mittelbar auf den Titanen zurückzugehen (Gebirge: Ort, an dem durch Atlas das Himmelsgewölbe gestützt wird, Rand der Welt. Kartenwerk: legendärer König von Mauretanien der nach dem Atlantik benannt ist, welcher wiederum selbst nach dem Titanen benannt ist), würden also wegfallen, selbst wenn Eigennamen akzeptiert werden.

Comment: @Chieron Ich kann mir, ehrlich gesagt, schwer vorstellen, dass ein arabisches Wort (Ǧibāl al-Aṭlas) von einem griechischen abstammt. Vor allem, weil der Atlas ja auch weit ausserhalb des historischen griechischen Einflußgebiets liegt und das Ende der bekannten Welt darstellte - Denke aber, das die Begrifflichkeiten so weit auseinanderliegen, dass man auch dann nicht von "einem gemeinsamen Wortstamm" sprechen kann.

Comment: @tofro "Homer und Herodot, die griechischen Dichter und Historiker aus der Antike, sahen im Atlas die westliche Grenze der damals bekannten Welt. Hier stützte Atlas das Himmelsgewölbe." (Wikipedia) Die arabische Sprache ist erst viel später in diese Gegend gekommen, und die Araber könnten den griechischen Namen durchaus übernommen haben. Die frz. WP führt auch noch zwei andere Theorien an, bleibt aber zu allen die Referenzen schuldig.

Answer (score -2):

> das Schloss

Spontane Kandidaten, bei denen ich erst im etymologischen Wörterbuch nachschlagen müsste:

> Rat, Zug, Stamm

Comment: Aber leitet sich das Schloss als Wohngebäude nicht vom abschließbaren Schloss ab? Beide kommen vom mhd. sloʒ, slōʒ, oder? http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Schlo%C3%9F

Comment: Es bringt nichts, hier einfach willkürlich Wörter mit mehreren Bedeutungen aufzulisten - die gibt es im Deutschen zuhauf, auch mit identischer Deklination. Die Schwierigkeit ist ja gerade die geforderte unterschiedliche Herkunft, und die solltest Du selbst begründen.