# Warum ist »Teekessel« ein Synonym für »Homonym«?

Tags: etymology, synonym

Aus einer [anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/29190/1487) geht klar hervor, dass »Teekessel« oder möglicherweise auch nur dessen Diminutiv »Teekesselchen« offenbar als Synonym für »Homonym« verwendet wird. Diese Verwendung von »Teekessel« habe ich schon früher und anderenorts bemerkt, und war damals wie jetzt sehr verwundert darüber.

Daher meine Frage:

Warum sagt man zu Homonymen »Teekessel«?

Comment: Vgl. "(Ich sehe was, was du nicht siehst) *und das ist*" sowie Fr. *ce qu'est que ...* (gesprochen ca. **sekess'ke**) "Es ist etwas ...".

Comment: @vectory: Wenn das eine Antwort sein soll, dann poste sie bitte als Antwort, nicht als Kommentar. Dann hast du auch mehr Raum um deine Gedanken verständlicher auszudrücken. Ich kann nämlich nicht erkennen, was dein Kommentar mit meiner Frage zu tun haben könnte.

Comment: Das hätte ich wohl getan, wenn mein Französisch nicht so schlecht wäre, dass die Phrase so scheinbar gar nicht existiert. Mir hatte erstmal der auto-vervollständigte Vorschlag in der Suche gereicht. Vgl. *Pontoon* < *Vingt-et-Un* (Blackjack, Siebzehn-und-Vier); Ich hege daher den Anfangsverdacht, es könnte sich um ein Mondegreen aus einer der vielen französischen Phrasen im obigen Sinne handeln. Mit einem der def. Artikel *le, la* wäre sogar ein *l* drin. Wer weiß ...

Comment: Vgl. auch https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1048/34192 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Begriff entstammt einem (bzw. ist der Name für ein) Gesellschaftsspiel ("Teapot"), das im Buch *The Book of a Hundred Games* von *Mary White* (1896) anscheinend zum ersten Mal beschrieben wurde. Leider erklärt das Buch selbst die Herkunft des Namens nicht. Der Name scheint willkürlich gewählt.
Das Spiel heißt auf deutsch "Teekesselchen". Im Spiel muss sich ein Spieler ein Homonym ausdenken und Schritt für Schritt die anderen Spieler an den Begriff heranführen, indem er die bezeichneten Begriffe so erklärt (Beispiel: "Bank"):

> - Mein Teekesselchen ist ein Gebäude
> - Mein Teekesselchen steht im Park
> - Mein Teekesselchen schreibt mir jeden Monat einen Brief
> - Mein Teekesselchen ist oft aus Holz oder aus Stein
>
> ....

Das Ziel ist, das "Teekesselchen" mit möglichst wenigen Beschreibungen zu erraten. Der "Witz" an dem Spiel ist, dass die Verwendung von Homonymen die Rater vollständig in die Irre führen kann, weil sie nicht wissen, welche Beschreibungen zur selben Bedeutung gehören.

Durch das Spiel und seine Bezeichnung hat sich der Begriff "Teekesselchen" für Homonyme eingebürgert.